# Copying values from one table to another table if it does not already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

I have four tables named Task, ProjectTeamMemeber, Hierarchy and Assignment.
Each Task is related to a Project through a Heirarchy and each Project has Team members which can be seen through ProjectTeamMember.

```
select 
    TH.TaskId As TaskID, P.PersonId As PersonID    
from 
    Task T
    Inner join Hierarchy TH on T.Id = TH.TaskId 
    Inner join ProjectTeamMemeber PTM on TH.ProjectId = P.TaskId
where 
    T.name = 'work'
```

The above query returns all the person allocated to a certain project where the Task name is 'work'

```
TaskId      PersonId
1347        50  
1350        50  
3377        50  
3403        598  
3411        1450  
3411        1454  
3411        1472
```

And I have another table Assigment from which i can see the Id of persons which are assigned to a particular task.

```
select 
    T.Id, A.PersonId
from
    Task T
    inner join Assignment A ON T.Id = A.TaskId
where 
    T.name = 'work'
```

The above query return all the persons allocated to Task called 'work'.

```
TaskId      PersonId
1347        50
1350        50
3411        1472
```

Now, what i have to achieve here is to allocate all the persons to a task with name 'work' which are allocated to projects which have a task name 'work'. Putting it simply i have to write some sql statements after which my second query above writtens the same result as my first query.

So far, I have tried to do this with cusrsors but it would not work. Below is the code for that

```
DECLARE @TaskId int
DECLARE @PersonId int
DECLARE @Id int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
select 
    TH.TaskId As TaskID, P.PersonId As PersonID    
from 
    Task T
    Inner join Hierarchy TH on T.Id = TH.TaskId 
    Inner join ProjectTeamMemeber PTM on TH.ProjectId = P.TaskId
where 
    T.name = 'work' 

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TaskId, @PersonId
BEGIN
    If not exists ( select 1 from Assignment where TaskId=@TaskId and PersonId=@PersonId)
    BEGIN
        EXEC GetUniqueIdentifier @Id OUTPUT;
        Insert INTO Assignment (Id, TaskId, PersonId) values (@Id, @TaskId, @PersonId)
    END
END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

(**NOTE** : I have to use the statement EXEC GetUniqueIdentifier @Id OUTPUT; to generate the Id. I know there maybe different and more reliable ways to generate Ids but due to some limitations i cannot change how the Id is being generated.)

**EDIT :**

Based on **LAMAK** answer i ran this

```
DECLARE @ids int
INSERT INTO Assignment (Id, TaskId, PersonId) 
EXEC GetUniqueIdentifier @ids OUTPUT;
SELECT 
    @ids,
    TH.TaskId As TaskID, 
    P.PersonId As PersonID,
FROM 
    Task T
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy TH on T.Id = TH.TaskId 
    INNER JOIN ProjectTeamMember P on TH.ProjectId = P.TaskId
WHERE 
    T.name = 'Customer work' 
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Assignment 
                WHERE TaskID = TH.TaskId
                AND PersonId = P.PersonId)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `CURSOR` for this, you can use a set based solution:

```
INSERT INTO Assignment (Id, TaskId, PersonId)
SELECT 
    NEWID(),
    TH.TaskId As TaskID, 
    P.PersonId As PersonID    
FROM 
    Task T
    INNER JOIN Hierarchy TH on T.Id = TH.TaskId 
    INNER JOIN ProjectTeamMemeber PTM on TH.ProjectId = P.TaskId
WHERE 
    T.name = 'work' 
    AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM Assignment 
                    WHERE TaskID = T.TaskId
                    AND PersonId = P.PersonId)
```

About the `NEWID()`, do you really need to check for collitions?, I think that is safe to assume that `NEWID()` will be unique if it's run on the same machine. And even on different servers, the probability for duplicated values is abysmally small.

**UPDATED**

Ok, so, you don't need an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` and you **have** to use the `GetUniqueIdentifier` sp (badly name also, since `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` is a datatype, wich can bring confusion). Then I'm affraid that you'll need to use a `CURSOR`. For the most part, your cursor seems fine, the only visible change being that you are not fetching for the next value of the cursor:

```
DECLARE @TaskId int
DECLARE @PersonId int
DECLARE @Id int

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
select 
    TH.TaskId As TaskID, P.PersonId As PersonID    
from 
    Task T
    Inner join Hierarchy TH on T.Id = TH.TaskId 
    Inner join ProjectTeamMemeber PTM on TH.ProjectId = P.TaskId
where 
    T.name = 'work' 

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TaskId, @PersonId
BEGIN
    If not exists (select 1 from Assignment where TaskId=@TaskId and PersonId=@PersonId)
    BEGIN
        EXEC GetUniqueIdentifier @Id OUTPUT;
        Insert INTO Assignment (Id, TaskId, PersonId) 
        values (@Id, @TaskId, @PersonId)
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @TaskId, @PersonId
END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: you migth be right about the newid but i have to do it the way as described above using the GetUniqueIdentifier procedure

Comment: @LivingThing *sigh*  what does the `GetUniqueIdentifier` returns?, can you post the code for it?

Comment: @LivingThing I really thought that your stored procedure was meant to return an `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`. This way it doesn't make much sense, why don't you use an `IDENTITY` column for this?

Comment: I have no control over over the procedure yet (i am a junior developer) and cannot avoid this procedure to generate unique identifiers. So, i have to use it the way it is and have to find a solution and live with that :/

Comment: No difference still the same result set

Comment: @LivingThing Then, please explain what is it that is not working, because *it would not work* doesn't give us much information

Comment: Going back to the question. After running this cursor the seond query should return the same result set as the first one. But it does not and has no effect whatsover meaning the second query returns the same result set(3 rows) as in the question

Comment: @LivingThing Can you create a sqlfiddle with a sample data so I can try to repro the issue?. (http://sqlfiddle.com)